# Populate a UITableView with videos in my Vimeo account

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, vimeo

How can I populate a UITableView with videos in my Vimeo account using swift?

I haven't tried anything yet since I don't even know where to start.

Comment: start from vimeo API https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking

Answer (score 1):

Start by looking through this documentation: [VIMNetworking](https://github.com/vimeo/VIMNetworking)

Sample app code can be found here: [Pegasus](https://github.com/vimeo/Pegasus)

After you authenticate and connect, make an API call to grab your videos, then display them from the JSON response into the uitableview.  (there are plenty of tutorials on how to populate a UITableView from a JSON response (etc)...